# Is there any way to make two steps in a one step for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using Python 3.8 and I was wandering if is there any way to make two steps in a one step for loop like this:

```
for i in range(15):
 if i == 2:
  # make two steps
 else:
  #continue normaly
```

Comment: Have you looked at the definition of the range function?

Comment: Yes but it's not like I want. I want if something happens to make two steps and otherwise one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manipulate the generator manually

```
gen = iter(range(15)) 
while True:
    try:
        i = next(gen) 
        if i ==2:
            next(gen) 
            continue 
        else:
            pass
    except: StopIteration
        break
```

Comment: TypeError: 'range' object is not an iterator

Comment: Oh, oops. Fixed it